# How to change the format in labels on horizontal bar graph in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to change the format in the labels using points separating miles and millions. I have, for example, 10327423 and I need this format: 10.327.423

I have a dataframe, called "df" with countries (Paises in Spanish) and number of infected (Contagiados in Spanish) per each country. Like this:
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHX1P.png)

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Row_list =[] 
for index, rows in df.iterrows(): 
     my_list =rows.Contagiados 
     Row_list.append(my_list) 
# Print the list 
print(Row_list) 
my_array = np.array(Row_list)
# printing my_array
print (my_array)
#
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_horizontal = ax.barh(df.Paises, df.Contagiados, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Contagiados')
plt.title('Contagiados por País')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 15

for index, value in enumerate(my_array):
    plt.text(value, index, str(value))
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmEWP.png)

Comment: Does the desired format always have 3 chars in the middle and 3 at the end?

Comment: All the dates have 3 chars in the middle and 3 at the end, but there is one date that has not the same amount. I need to put a point for every three numbers counting from the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to format the number in another way. As '.' is not commonly used for number separator you can set ',' and use a replace

```
plt.text(value, index, str('{:,}'.format(value).replace(',','.')))
```